# Static Context from Activity.onStart()

Tags: java, android, static, android-context

I am trying to generate a notification from a class, `Utilities.java`, outside of the subclass of `Context`. I've thought about providing a `SingletonContext` class and have looked at posts ike [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002288/static-way-to-get-context-on-android). I'd like to be able to `return != null` `Context` object since the notification can be generated at any given time because it is generated from a `messageReceived()` callback.

What are there downsides to doing something like this:

```
public static Context c;    

public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    @Override
    public void onStart()
      super.onStart()
      c = this.getApplicationContext();
}

//other method somewhere outside this class
public Context getContext(){
   return MainActivity.c
}
```

I don't think it would be any different than putting this on the `onCreate()`, however, it guarantees that the context is up to date when the activity starts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Context keeps a reference to this activity in memory, which you might not want. Perhaps use

```
this.getApplicationContext();
```

instead. This will still let you do file IO and most other things a context requires. Without a specific reference to this activity.

Comment: do you mean making c = this.getApplicationContext() within the onStart()? You're right, doing this.getApplicationContext() will actually return the Context instead of the Activity. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should overwrite the onResume Method.
If you open a new activity, and switch back, the onStart method will not getting invoked.

Android Lifecycle: [doc](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html#lifecycle-states)

BTW: I read about problems with ApplicationContext using a dialog or toast, so if you use the context to create on of these you should use your Activity as context.